# Python / Pandas compare rows by grouped columns and update value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe which is list of all previous races of a contenders and the associated trainer. Note that the trainer changes over time.

```
      Date       R   H   Fin  Trainer 
0     11182017   1   1   2     1      
1     12182017   2   1   1     1      
2     01182018   5   1   6     2      
3     02182018   8   1   2     2      
4     01182018   1   2   1     2     
5     02182018   3   2   5     3      
6     03182018   3   2   2     3
```

I want to be compare each race to the previous race by date and by H, identify when the "Trainer" changes then denote how many times with that trainer

Results Example below

```
      Date       R   H   Fin  Trainer #
0     11182017   1   1   2     1      1
1     12182017   2   1   1     1      2
2     01182018   5   1   6     2      1
3     02182018   8   1   2     2      2
4     01182018   1   2   1     2      1
5     02182018   3   2   5     3      1
6     03182018   3   2   2     3      2
```

Thanks for the help and suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
In [11]: df.groupby(["H", "Trainer"]).cumcount() + 1
Out[11]:
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    2
4    1
5    1
6    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks that makes sense, but I want to write the result back to the dataframe as a new column. Thoughts? Use a key and merge?

Comment: @Derek `df["#"] = df.groupby(["H", "Trainer"]).cumcount() + 1`